# Google sign in iOS bug

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google auth in my iOS application.

I'm in my appDelegate and I'm trying to implement this function

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options:  [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool 
{
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url as URL!, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

I'm getting an error on this part of the function:

```
 options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String
```

The error is

> ```
> ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
> ```

Im not sure what is happening. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try your code to this :)

```
private func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: URL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,
                                                    sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication.rawValue] as? String,
                                                    annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation.rawValue])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]` to `annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey] as? String`

Comment: That didn't  fix it. what do you think the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Here r the fantastic answer:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,
                                    sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!,
                                    annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

reference from

[Trouble handling Google sign in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136785/trouble-handling-google-sign-in-swift-3)