# Trouble handling Google sign in Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, oauth

I am new to iOS and am having trouble with app delegate URL handling in Swift 3, and I could really use some pointers.

The below code works perfectly fine in Swift 2.3:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
  openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
        sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
        annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}


func application(application: UIApplication,
  openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    var options: [String: AnyObject] = [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey: sourceApplication,
                                        UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey: annotation]
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)
}
```

When I paste the swift 2.3 code straight from the Firebase website, Xcode prompts me that a lot of the methods have changed. In particular, the `options` object.

In Swift 2.3, I can access the source application using `options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]` and the annotation using `options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]`

Xcode prompts me to change it to `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication._rawValue as String` and `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation._rawValue as String`

Yet when I make the suggested changes, Google returns a URL, but nothing happens. Instead of redirecting to the app, it proceeds to enter the local google site, for me: www.google.co.nz

The full Swift 3 version I have looks like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
                 openURL url: NSURL,
                 options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    print(UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication._rawValue as String)
    print(UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation._rawValue as String)

    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,
                                             sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication._rawValue as String] as! String!,
                                             annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation._rawValue as String])
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
             openURL url: NSURL,
             sourceApplication: String?,
             annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    var options: [String: AnyObject] = [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication._rawValue as String: sourceApplication as AnyObject,
                                        UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation._rawValue as String: annotation!]

    print(UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication._rawValue as String)
    print(UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation._rawValue as String)

    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,
                                             sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                             annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Xcode 8 Swift 3**

If you are using multiple URL Schemes along with Google Sign In, use it like this:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    if(url.scheme!.isEqual("fbXXXXXXXXXXX")) {
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)

    } else {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,
                                    sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!,
                                    annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is amazing! just out of interest, where would you search for this. I can't seem to find it in the docs anywhere.

Comment: You are right. These minute details are nowhere in the docs. You just have to dig in inside the UIKit Library. Read and try to emulate things the way it is done in Apple's code :)

Comment: Oh yikes! That's going to be quite the adventure :P thank you for the tip though! will definitely dive deeper next time :)

Comment: Thanks, Saved my time

Comment: From now only use `return (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.handle(url))!`

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4, Xcode 9**

If you are using multiple URLSchemes for ***facebook*** and ***Google*** SignIn:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
   let fbSignIn     = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
   let googleSignIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

   return fbSignIn || googleSignIn
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**For swift 5 Xcode 10.3 (Latest google signin)**

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        let googleDidHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)

        return googleDidHandle
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        let googleDidHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)

        return googleDidHandle
    }
```

**To open signIn screen on Button click**

```
@IBAction func btnGoogleSigninClick(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform any operations at function "signIn" in AppDelegate.

After Google sends you some data:

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
            withError error: NSError!) {

    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let userId = user.userID
        // Perform some operation to change the scene.
        // ........

    }
    else {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Maybe the code below can give you some idea:

```
let myStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)

let protectedPage = myStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProtectedPageViewController") as! ProtectedPageViewController

let protectedPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: protectedPage)

let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = protectedPageNav
```

??? I reference from YouTube's video "Sign-in with Google Account button. Example in Swift. Video 2", that are provided from "Sergey Kargopolov".

and...

I have a question similar to this and didn't solve it...

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it didn't help me in this circumstance, but if you still have that similar error, the above answer worked for me. Good Luck! :D

Comment: Why I use above answer, and compiler show ~

Use of unresolved identifier "SDKApplicatinoDelegate"

for me? :'(

Comment: Ah just a typo. I just put FB in front to make FBSDK

Comment: Did it end up working for you too? :) If not I could post my full app delegate later tonight.

Comment: Ohya I fixed it, now it can leave login page and back to my app. :D

But my code have some problem when get Google users data, could you give me the part that function named ""sign" or "signIn"? 

Thank u ~~~

Comment: sure thing :) just check the original question for an edit section in about 10hrs or so. I'm just out at the moment so I can't access Xcode haha

Comment: awesome stuff!  :)

Answer (score 0):

While n.by.n answer is okay I saw a better answer in another thread (Swift 2.3):

```
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]) {
    return true
} else if something else {
    return true
} else {
    return false 
}
```